# how to save mutiple chart in single pdf doc in c# window application

Tags: c#, pdf, window

[chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOb3N.png)

this chart generated for one product how to save multiple chart in one pdf document or save chart in pdf using c# in window application
.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with DocumentCore class. The document core steps available in this link

[DocumentCore](https://sautinsoft.com/products/document/examples/create-pdf-document-net-csharp-vb.php?gclid=Cj0KCQjw7Z3VBRC-ARIsAEQifZTWjqyeaOIYAq-rIJZESq7O1dQlDLtK1NE4HKr3BVeFBrh7mx-uB30aAtEpEALw_wcB)

Comment: If you are not even sure about it you should put this in a comment instead of a link-only answer..